# How do I map nested array into lists in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am having trouble mapping array of arrays as lists in React.

Here is my current react code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class BuySell extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataDepth: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://indodax.com/api/depth/btcidr").then((getData) => {
      console.log(getData);
      this.setState({
        dataDepth: [getData.data],
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const dataBuy = this.state.dataDepth.map((item, index) => {
      var listBuy = [item.buy];
      return <li key={index}>{listBuy}</li>;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>GET DATA:</h1>
        <ul>{dataBuy}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BuySell;
```

The current output is:

- 4464800000.044890354464280000.000025644460200000.010089234460010000.148459314460000000.008713044458480000.000300004457940000.000256224457610000.148539244457490000.148543244...

(edited) what I expect:

- 4464800000
- 4464280000
- 4460200000
- 4460010000
- and so on

(the first index of each array items)

the API data is:

```
{
    "buy": [
        [
            447500000,
            "0.03443557"
        ],
        [
            447216000,
            "0.00022361"
        ],
        [
            447198000,
            "0.00234181"
        ],
        [
            447142000,
            "0.00002564"
        ],
so on
}
```

Comment: Why is `[item.buy]` being converted to an array?

Comment: You should probably show an example of the data coming back from the API (if `item.buy` is an array, then that would explain what you see) and explain how you want to show this nested array data.

Comment: edited, I have included the API data

Comment: Do you see any console errors? I would expect `dataDepth.map` to throw, as the data returned is an object not an array.

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's being put into an array: `dataDepth: [getData.data],`, so the `map` only iterates once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP expected response has changed, this will get you were you want to be.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://indodax.com/api/depth/btcidr").then((getData) => {
      console.log(getData);
      this.setState({
        dataDepth: getData.data.buy,
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const dataBuy = this.state.dataDepth.map(([number], index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{number}</li>;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Coba get data</h1>
        <ul>{dataBuy}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/nihiser-the-sans/pen/MWbgzLY

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU! THIS SOLVES IT! yes I initially misunderstood the API data at first, and finally updated it with the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have too many arrays.

Try this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://indodax.com/api/depth/btcidr").then((getData) => {
      console.log(getData);
      this.setState({
        dataDepth: getData.data,
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const dataBuy = this.state.dataDepth.buy.map(([num ,decimal], index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{num}{decimal}</li>;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Coba get data</h1>
        <ul>{dataBuy}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for responding! what i get is this error: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @Buddgee make sure `this.setState.dataDepth` is not undefined first.

Comment: This would indicate that your data is not as you mentioned it or undefined. To remove the `.buy` from the map

Comment: It means the promise is not resolved yet and data is not loaded, but the UI is rendered and data is undefined. You need to create a spinner for loading the UI until the promise is resolved

Comment: in `componentDidMount` set dataDepth to `getData.data.buy` and remove the `.buy.` from the `map`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the subarray values to be same all the time, you can simply define the element [0] and [1].

Code Sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-chebyshev-1tri3?file=/src/App.js:0-449

How about the code below,

```
import React from "react";

const apiData = {
  buy: [
    [447500000, "0.03443557"],
    [447216000, "0.00022361"],
    [447198000, "0.00234181"],
    [447142000, "0.00002564"]
  ]
};

export default function App() {
  const listItems = apiData.buy.map((item) => {
    return (
      <li>
        {item[0]}{item[1]}
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```